# How to load javascript dependencies with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable, turbolinks

In a Rails application, I am using turbolinks and jquery-turbolinks. I have some big javascript dependencies, like dataTables. First, I was loading all those dependencies on the application.js but in the end, I have on big file on 1Mo after precompilation so I want to load dependencies only when they are required.

I created a file called `custom-datables.coffe` with this content :

```
#= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
#= require datatables

$(document).ready ->
  console.log $('.data-table').dataTable
```

I included it like this :

```
- content_for :javascript do
  = javascript_include_tag 'custom-datatables'
```

And I yield javascript at the end of my application layout.

It works when I refresh the page but when I go to this page using turbolinks I can see than `$('.data-table').dataTable` is undefined. When I type `$('.data-table').dataTable` in the firefox's console, the function is defined. `$(document).ready` seems to be triggered before the complete load of datatable.

Is there a way to fix it? Is it the best practice to load big dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

When using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) you should use the `page:change` event, instead of the document ready.

So in your case:

```
$(window).bind 'page:change', () ->
  console.log $('.data-table').dataTable
```

I generally prefer the one big application.js file, because after first load it will be cached in your clients browser. Also in production it will be minified and compressed.

Comment: The action is never triggered. The problem with a single big file it than it's long to load. My page take 20 seconds to load and I'm looking for a way to increase speed.

Comment: Never triggered? That is weird. Do you have a javascript error? Which version of turbolinks are you using (although I am pretty sure the event was always called that way). You are sure your browser has the new javascript code?